# Using Segue Without Viewing View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to coding, so any help is appreciated!

Basically, the app I'm building consists of passing data to another view controller. All I want is for the data to be passed, without the user physically viewing the View Controller its being passed too. I set up segues and it passes fine to the other View Controller.

The code I have written in the screenshot, eg. `let DestViewController : ViewTwo - segue.destinationViewController as! ViewTwo` allows to view the data on the other view controller.

My question being, what code do I edit or add to this line, in order to still have the data passed- without the user physically viewing the controller its being passed too? 
I assumed some type of '`nil`' would be implemented in this line of code, but it doesn't seem to work when I do so.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: how about delegates or notification?

Comment: What is the purpose to pass data to a controller which will not be presented?

Comment: @vadian I have two user log ins. Client and customer. When the client logs in, I want them to be able to type in information- to send to the customers view controller. I just don't want the client to be redirected to customers view.

Answer (score 1):

Segues are meant to goto another View Controller.

In order to pass data from one view to another without moving, you can use either **NSNotificationCentre** or **Delegates**.

Comment: I'm not familiar with NSNotifcationCentre. Would I keep the code I have and just implement NSNotificationCentre in it? Or do I have to do something completely different/start over?

Comment: No don't have to re-do things. Just implement it. Set an Observer and Call the observer.

Comment: Trying this now. Thank you!

Comment: Great! But for `NSNotificationCenter` to work, the `View Controller` must be loaded once, where the `addObserver` is added.

Comment: Other option will be to take _Global variables_ to store these values and when other view is loaded fetch values from these variable and user them accordingly. Use whichever suits your requirement.

Comment: Sorry, coding is very new to me. How would I load the View Controller once? To give you an overall picture, I basically have two user log ins set up- client and customer. When the client logs in, I want them to type in information to send to the customers view controller (without the client being redirected to their view controller). I have this set up, but I'm being redirected to the customers view controller. Would NSNoticationCenter still be okay for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124927/discussion-between-mr-ub-and-deborah-elizabeth-padilla).

Answer (score 0):

When the method `prepareForSegue(segue:sender:)` is called, the transition to an other scene is already in progress (not visually).

In order to pass data through a transition, this is the best way to do it.

However, if you want to pass data to a view controller to be shown later, I would advice you to simply store it in a variable (array maybe in your case) and at the transition, give it to your destination view controller.
You can also store it in a shared variable between your two view controllers (static property, ...), but I wouldn't advice you to do so for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question:

Consider:

- ParentViewController as the controller currently visible.
- ChildViewController as the hidden controller you wish to pass data to.

You want to create a reference to your ChildViewController from your ParentViewController.

If you're using a Storyboard, you can achieve this by adding a ContainerView to your ParentViewController in InterfaceBuilder.  That will create an embedded View Controller.  You can make that invisible, by setting the underlying View you added in your ParentViewController as `hidden`

When your *ParentViewController* loads, the `prepareForSegue` will actually get called w/ the embedded *ChildViewController*.  You can then assign it to a local property in order to retain a reference to it.

```
var destViewController: ViewTwo!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let childVC = segue.destination as? ViewTwo{

        self.destViewController = childVC
    }
}

func addDataToChildViewController(){
    destViewController.textLabel.text = self.textField1.text
    ...
}
```

Now, I would like to point out that there's a strong chance that using a ViewController in this manor is not an ideal solution.  ViewControllers are meant to display Views.  If you are not doing that, then you probably want to re-think this solution.

Answer (score -1):

You could try setting up a singleton to store data:

```
class DataSingleton {
  static let sharedInstance = DataSingleton()
  //Add variables to store here
}

//Referencing
let singleton = DataSingleton.sharedInstance
singleton.theVariable
```